# Extracting speciific string in Python

Tags: python, string

I have log file in wich at some point I added timestam creation and now it look like this:
`log.txt:`

```
327555
327563
327570
327601
2012-11-19 22:21:37 :: 327001
2012-11-19 22:21:37 :: 327004
2012-11-19 22:21:37 :: 327007
2012-11-19 22:21:37 :: 327008
```

In my Python script i used to read all lines from log.txt and add it line-by-line to a set for futher usage:

```
log_file = open('log.txt')
set_log = set([])
for line in log_file:
    set_log.add(line.strip())
log_file.close()
```

But since timestam was added this solution and gives me wrong values in my set ( it includes timestam as well).

Q: How to make it more flexible, so it udersteads lines without timestams and WITH timestams and extract only proper values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just parse away the timestamps. `ln.split()[-1]` will return the last element after splitting on whitespace, which seems to be what you're after, so

```
set_log = set(ln.split()[-1] for ln in log_file)
```

(Using a generator comprehension to replace your loop. The `strip()` is no longer needed as `split()` removes all whitespace.)